# Get the geolocation of a tweet

Tags: objective-c, twitter, geolocation

I an conducting a Twitter search and need to get the exact location of each tweet to plot on a map. I have set up core location and my code for 'fetching the tweets' is as below.

I am currently looping through to get the text component but I am unsure how to also get the location component that accompanies the tweet. You will see a couple of lines below that I have added to the loop to try and extract the location, however it is coming up blank / null.

• Am I positioning the NSString *twitlocation in the correct location in the loop? will this collected location marry up with the correct text for each tweet is I call it from separate arrays, i.e the text from tweet 1 and the location from tweet 1 will marry up when I run objectAtIndex:0 ? • Why is the log for twitterLocation null? • Am I correct in putting the locations in a NSString to add to an array or should it be a different object?

FYI's

- All objects have been declared in .h file - The twitText works correctly and I can get the tweets text for each tweet - twitterLocation is a NSMutableArray

Thanks!

```
- (void)fetchTweets
        {
            AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


            //NSLog(@"phrase carried over is %@", delegate.a);

            // Do a simple search, using the Twitter API
            TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%@", delegate.a]] 
                                                     parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

            // Notice this is a block, it is the handler to process the response
            [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
             {
                 if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) 
                 {
                     // The response from Twitter is in JSON format
                     // Move the response into a dictionary and print
                     NSError *error;        
                     NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
                     //NSLog(@"Twitter response: %@", dict);

                     NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey:@"results"];


                     //Loop through the results


                     for (NSDictionary *tweet in results) {
                         // Get the tweet
                         NSString *twittext = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
                         //looping through to also get the location of each tweet
                         NSString *twitlocation = [tweet objectForKey:@"location"];

                         // Save the tweet to the twitterText array
                         [_twitterText addObject:twittext];
                         //adding the twitlocation to the location array
                        [twitterLocation addObject:twitlocation];
                     }

                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.tableView reloadData];

                     });


                      NSLog(@"MY ************************LOCATION************** %@", twitterLocation);


                 }

                 else
                     NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
             }];



        }
```

Comment: For what are you searching for? I mean with the http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%@" url?

Comment: Have you tried fetching a tweet you know it has geolocation data attached to it? Chances are the ones you're retrieving don't have that metadata associated and thus the nil you're getting

Comment: The token at the end is for a particular search (i.e it will have a #searchterm associated with it) - I know that this part works. Just imagine that the search term is a keyword associated with tweets. ale0xb, that is the issue - how do I search to make sure that I recieve the geo data and then how do I loop through the tweeets to extract this as I am doing with the objectForKey:@"text"?